# How would you translate the phrase "Concession Speech" in Chinese accurately?

Tags: translation

The following is the title of an [article](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/11/09/us/politics/donald-trump-won-now-what.html) from NewYork Times:

> *Highlights of Hillary Clinton’s Concession Speech and President Obama’s Remarks*

How would you translate "concession speech" in Chinese *accurately*?

"Concession" means "让步，承让". But it seems rather weired to say "让步演讲，承让演讲". In this Chinese [article](http://news.ifeng.com/a/20161110/50233024_0.shtml), it seems  to suggest that one might translate it as "败选演讲". But "败选" seems to be rather inferior to "concession" in English.

Answer (score 4):

I found these:

How about: 认输演说 or 认输演讲 or 败选演讲

Example of the latter:

麦凯恩在大选之夜的败选演讲中做手势让支持者冷静下来.

Comment: jukuu agrees：1.  concession speech
 认输演说

Comment: in Taiwan, we use 敗選演說, which can be abbreviated as 敗選演 http://www.appledaily.com.tw/realtimenews/article/new/20161110/985723/

Answer (score 0):

I would rather go with 退讓宣言，as it is matches the style of the original.

Comment: 宣言 is an announcement, not a speech

Answer (score 0):

To concede(承认失败) means " to admit (defeat) after previously denied". 
Since "concession speech" refers to "admit defeat in an election", the full transaction should be 承认竞选失败的演说
And contract to 败选演说 / 败选演讲 is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

maybe "妥協演說"? in which "妥協" roughly means "compromise"

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000054800

Comment: 妥協 means "compromise" exactly. Not suitable for replacing concession